# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit only showing 2.9GB of memory

Tags: 10.04, memory, ram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is more than 3GB of RAM not recognised when using amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20571/why-is-more-than-3gb-of-ram-not-recognised-when-using-amd64)

I have installed ubuntu 10.04 lts (64bit) on my lenovo thinkpad X60 (Core 2 Duo T5600). I installed 4gb of ram before installing ubuntu, but when I check the available memory in Ubuntu it says that only 2.9gb is installed. I have checked the bios and it shows the full 4gb of ram. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to the Mobile Intel 945GM Express chipset in your laptop.

[This site](http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/lenovo-thinkpad-x60-1706/1707-3121_7-32522014.html), suggests your computer uses the 945GM Express,and the top answer on [Why is more than 3GB of RAM not recognised when using amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20571/why-is-more-than-3gb-of-ram-not-recognised-when-using-amd64) gives a more complete explanation.